# FTPS suddenly failing across all Azure Web Apps

Tags: ftp, azure-web-app-service, ftps

I have over 10 Azure Web Apps for which i've been able to manually upload file to using FTPS for over 3 years.  Now all of a sudden on Mac Client and Win10 client and other peoples computers we're all getting the same errors preventing manual access.  This happens across multiple subscriptions as well. As far as i'm aware the pipeline is still releasing with ZipDeploy without any issues so this seems to be a FTP/FTPS only issue.

```sh
Status: Resolving address of waws-prod-dm1-081.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net
Status: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:990...
Status: Connection established, initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Status: TLS connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (40,69,166,81,39,156).
Command:    LIST
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
Error:  GnuTLS error -110: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
Status: Server did not properly shut down TLS connection
Error:  The data connection could not be established: ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted
Response:   550 The network connection was aborted by the local system. 
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

Comment: Just in case of recent changes I followed the instructions on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-ftp and both App and User credentials failed to work while connecting with FTPS

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out a patch was required for the Switch being used across the network. IT updated a bunch of the switches and this issue resolved itself.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, reconnect with FTP and FTPS both ways, sometime these connections are not stable, just delete the "s" in FTPS endpoint you will get the FTP endpoint.

If it still fail you could go to your application settings and check whether your FTP access is Disable.
[image]

Check the time-out setting, set this in FileZilla client, go to Edit, Settings, Connection, FTP, and check "Send FTP keep-alive commands" checkbox.

If all these couldn't solve it, please configure firewall setting.

Hope this could help you, if you still have other questions, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion George.  It looks like it's currently an issue only when on Microsoft's Campus.  I will update again when I know the exact details.